# Mongo response from mongo template not being mapped properly into java object

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, jsonschema2pojo

I have a java pojo created by jsonSchemaPojo2 as so:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
   "CardBranding"
})

public class RewardsProcessing implements Serializable
{
    @JsonProperty("CardBranding")
    @NotNull
    private String cardBranding

    public RewardsProcessing(String cardBranding){
         this.cardBranding = cardBranding
    }

    @JsonProperty("CardBranding")
    public String getCardBranding(){return cardBranding; }
    
    @JsonProperty("CardBranding")
    public void setCardBranding(String cardBranding){ this.cardBranding = cardBranding}

}
```

Rewards Collection:

```
[
 {CardBranding : "1"},
 {CardBranding : "2"}
]
```

The following code parses the mongo response into the java pojo

```
AggregationResults results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "Rewards", RewardsProcessing.class);
```

The problem  is that I am getting null in the resulting java object. aggregate is case sensitive.

I have two options:

1. Make the cardBranding field upper-case by using some property in the jsonschemapojo2. I tried researching but found none. Schemapojo2 by default sets the field to lowerCase.
2. Configure the aggregate method to ignore the case.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@JsonProperty` which is used by jackson, use `@Field` annotation for the field.

```java
@Field("CardBranding")
private String cardBranding
```

Need to import annotation using
`import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;`